# How to change values in ui-autocomplete class for google map api

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am calling jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css in my html code for google map.

While entering value in field box for location I get list to select location. This location list name is currently getting position at wrong place on my screen and I want to change its position. But I dont know in which script should I change this. While debugging it says internally calling class ui-autocomplete and below values it shows. I want to change "top" and "left" value in original source called script. Where to do that?

```
enter code here

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Elements called:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-   all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -1868px; left: 147.516px; display: none; width: 1013px; position: relative;"><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kerman, Iran</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Aden, Yemen</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Ilam, Ilam, Iran</a></li></ul>



element.style {
z-index: 1;
top: -1851px;
left: 147.516px;
display: none;
position: relative;
width: 1013px;
```

}

Thanks,
Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

ok I got the answer.

```
open : function(){
    $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").css({top:"+=5",left:"-=2"});
},
```